# wildcard in regular expression in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a question regarding wildcard in shell script regular exression
vi a.sh

```
if [[ $1 == 1*3 ]]; then
  echo "matching"
else
  echo "not matching"
fi
```

If I run `sh a.sh 123` the output is: "matching".

But according to http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm:

> * (asterisk)
>
> the proceeding item is to be matched zero or more times. ie. n* will
>   match n, nn, nnnn, nnnnnnn but not na or any other character.

it should match to only 3,13,113,111..3.

But why is it matching 123?

Comment: This is glob pattern not regex. Here `1*3` will match anything that starts with `1` and ends with `3`

Comment: If you wanted a regex test, that would be `[[ $1 =~ 1*3 ]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [documentation you linked](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) you are taking the part in which it talks about "Regular expressions".

However, what is important here is what is within "Standard Wildcards (globbing patterns)":

> ### Standard Wildcards (globbing patterns)
>
> **this can represent any number of characters** (including zero, in other words, zero or more characters). If you specified a "cd*" it
>   would use "cda", "cdrom", "cdrecord" and anything that starts with
>   “cd” also including “cd” itself. "m*l" could by mill, mull, ml, and
>   anything that starts with an m and ends with an l.

That is, it does not refer to the previous character but to a set of characters (zero or more). It is what equivalent to a `.*` in normal regular expressions.

So the expression `1*3` matches anything starting with `1` + zero or more characters + `3` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different pattern matching you find in the Unix/Linux World:

- **Regular Expressions**: This is the complex pattern matching you find in `grep`, `sed`, and many other utilities. As time moved on, many extensions can be found. These extensions are referred to in POSIX as *original* (now considered obsolete), *modern*, and *extended*.
- **Globbing**: This refers to the file matching you find when you do things such as `*.txt` to match all text files. These are much simpler and less extensive. There are a few extensions (like `**` to match subdirectories in Ant).

When you use `[[ ... == ... ]]` *without quotes* in Bash, you are using globbing file matches. If you want to use regular expressions, you need to use the `=~` operator:

```
if [[ $foo =~ ^11*3 ]]   # Matches 13, 113, 1113, 11113
then
```